# Maxtrac 300 speaker

Tags: equipment, speaker, motorola

How do I make the internal speaker work on a Maxtrac 300 With the 5 Pin accessory port
on the back of it. My other radio has 16 pins and i jumped 15/16 for that one But lost on how to do this one.. Thank You for the help
Allan B

Comment: Hello Allan, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: I did quite a bit of searching just now, and the only thing concerning a Motorola Maxtrac 5-pin port found was [here](http://www.repeater-builder.com/motorola/maxtrac/maxtrac-discr-audio.html). There are other pages there, with many links (which I did not follow).

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem Internal speaker wire missing Put that in and all is good

Comment: Glad you fixed it! Please mark this as accepted. :-)